# php send json data commented

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I've created contact form that send form data to an email
then I'm sending ajax  to the server which returns json response with success message or alert message
but I'm getting the data commented as below :

```
<!-- TESS -->

 
 
//  {"type":"success","message":"Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!"}
```

this is the php code  :

```
try
{

    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');
            
    $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email 
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    // All the neccessary headers for the email.
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );
    
    // Send email
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
   
}

// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

and the js code :

```
    // when the form is submitted
    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {

        // if the validator does not prevent form submit
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "../../forms/contact.php";

            // POST values in the background the the script URL
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    // data = JSON object that contact.php returns

                    // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the 
                    
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    console.log(alertBox,messageText);
                                        console.log("data ",data,data.type,data.message);

                    // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        // console.log("messages ok")
                        // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                        $('.messages').append(alertBox);
                        // empty the form
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
```

this code is taken from this tutorial
[HOW TO BUILD A WORKING BOOTSTRAP CONTACT FORM](https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the response should be in json format but it returns  <!-- TESS -->

 
 
//  {"type":"success","message":"Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!"}

Comment: Do you use any file or code other than that?

Comment: I attached this part of code related to the question you can find the full code in this tutorial https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form

Comment: use try catch code between `ob_start();` and `ob_get_clean();`

Comment: The page where you have written php code may be having `<!-- TESS --> //`

Comment: That's weird. I have tested it and it works perfectly

Comment: Do a global string search in your project and look for `<!-- TESS -->`. It should be somewhere.

Comment: @kosmos you're right i found that there was a syntax error in my file